# Is it possible to connect a HDMI port to a thunderbolt port?

Tags: hdmi, thunderbolt

I have a Mac Mini 2012, I need to connect it to a 27" iMac 2013 thunderbolt port. Both run Yosemite.
Is this possible? No one seems to sell an adapter...'

Comment: Hdmi to thunderbolt? I've seen it sold...

Comment: It sounds like you're trying to transfer data between them.. But your subject matter seems contradictory, as you make reference to HDMI. Can you elaborate on what you're trying to do?

Answer (score 1):

27" iMacs do have Target Display Mode available, so you can connect your Mac mini to your iMac via HDMI.

I know Belkin makes a male – male HDMI – Mini DisplayPort cable, and I'd bet Monoprice does too.

If I'm not mistaken (and on this point, I well could be), Target Display can only function at 720p, so that is a caveat to consider.

Also bear in mind, this just makes the iMac behave as an external display. You can't transfer data using this method.

Comment: Thaanks for the response, I need to use the existing Thunderbolt port on the Mini in Target mode to connect to the iMac. I've tried a HDMI to VGA adapter and while it works from the HDMI port on my Startech dock (connected to the iMac) it won't work from the HDMI port on the Mini! The Mini will however run the monitor from the Thunderbolt port...thats why I need a HDMI to Thunderbolt lead...